# PHP - Issues with array of sizes and selecting best sizes with least waste

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a function that will accept a size in feet ($total) and select from a stock set of sizes that I have (array(10,12,15,20,24,30)) to equal the total without any left over.

I got it working where if it's under 30 to find the nearest to 30 but after that I am having issues with over 30. I haven't touch PHP in over 8 years and I am behind on the learning curve and figured I would pick a brain or two to help.

Example: total is 44, best option is (24 and 20) vs (30 and 15) or is total is 64, best option is (20, 20, 24) vs (30, 30, 10)

Comment: What if it is 9 for example? Or anything where you would have leftover?

Comment: This class of problem is not exactly easy to solve efficiently...

Comment: putvande---anything like 9 would have to have a leftover as the minumum is 10 which I figured out ... its when you go over 30 where it would require more than one part to make a total.

Marc B--- I know... I am trying everything I can think of but its over 8 years since I touched PHP and now I am learning from scratch again and trying to figure this puzzle out.

Comment: @Sanchit function closest($array, $number){
    if($i = array_search( $number, $array)) return $i;
    $array[] = $number;
    sort($array);
    $i = array_search($number, $array);
    if($i && isset($array[$i+1])) return $array[$i+1];
    return null;
}

$width = $_POST['width'];
$headersizes = array(10,12,15,20,24,30);
if ($width < 31) {
        $headers=0;
        $header=closest($headersizes,$width);
} else {


$header=closest($headersizes,$width);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?

function get_smallest_in($value, $set) {
    $retval = 0;
    foreach ($set as $item) {
        if ($item <= $value && (($item <= $retval || $retval == 0) || $item == $value )) {
            $retval = $item;
        }
    }
    return $retval;
}

function get_sizes($total, $set) {
    $retval = array();
    while($total > 0) {
        if (min($set) <= $total) {
            $temp = get_smallest_in($total, $set);
            if ($temp != 0) {
                array_push($retval, $temp);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
            $total -= $temp;
        }
        else {
            if ($total > min($set) / 2) {
                array_push($retval, min($set));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    foreach ($retval as $key => &$value) {
        for ($index = 0; $index < count($retval); $index++) {
            if ($key != $index) {
                if (in_array($value + $retval[$index], $set)) {
                    $value= $retval[$index] + $value;
                    $retval[$index] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $retval;
}

$set = array(10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 30);
print_r(get_sizes(64, $set));

?>
```

Output is `Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 30 [3] => 10 [4] => 24 )`. If you want it to take 20, 20, 24 instead of 30, 10, 24 you will have to do that yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Sinomai!!! I can definately use this. Its all downhill from here.

Comment: Testing shows that anything under 10 is showing as zero... Ex.. 33 shows Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 30 ) when it should show Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 10 [2] => 30 ). Suggestions?

Comment: Yea, its made to not go above the value at all. I just edited the answer to add the smallest value when there is no other value that can fit. (warning, this will add a value of 10 for 1 or 20 for 11)

Comment: nvm i just edited again and will find best fit better (see lines 25, 26 and 27)